# Circular Typedefs

Tags: c++, typedef, circular-dependency

This code fails to compile:

```
class B;
class A{
  typedef int AThing;
  typedef B::BThing BThing;
};
class B{
  typedef int BThing;
  typedef A::Athing AThing;
};
```

Because `A` needs a `typedef` from `B` and `B` needs one from `A`.

What is the typical method for using typedefs that have circular dependancies?

Comment: not a duplicate IMO, there are no header includes here, let alone circular dependencies in header includes

Comment: Dunno why I can't answer, so will do it here. This is definitely not a duplication, and pretty difficult question indeed! This case can be resolved by adding one more level of indirection: [see demo](https://godbolt.org/g/jx5IC9). I faced with pretty same case and I'm looking for more general and useful solution right now.

Comment: @Trollliar That is an interesting way of solving that problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution for having circular `typedef` dependencies of this kind is to not have circular `typedef` dependencies of this kind. These kinds of circular `typedef` dependencies cannot be done in C++, so you have to rearrange your class hierarchy:

```
class B;

typedef int this_is_a_BThing;

class A{
  typedef int AThing;
  typedef this_is_a_Bthing BThing;
};
class B{
  typedef this_is_a_BThing BThing;
  typedef A::Athing AThing;
};
```

Comment: That stinks......oh well

Answer (score 0):

> What is the typical method for using typedefs that have circular dependancies?

There's no such *typical method*, you cannot do that.

For cases how you can use forward declarations and expand dependent typedefs in scope of types see the answers from [Resolve header include circular dependencies in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies-in-c).

The case you are introducing a `typedef` at class scope doesn't matter much about the fact that the compiler cannot resolve it from seeing a forward declaration.

---

The only way I can think of using typedefs is to use the [Pimpl Idion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) and actually introduce them in the implementation only.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.....it is a separate issue entirely